# Symfony2 Doctrine2 Inheriting an Entity in another Bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Trying to create 2 bundles. One is a portal and the other is a training bundle. The thing that I'm having trouble grasping is how to create an entity in the portal bundle that inherits an entity in the training bundle (and overwrites the training bundles entity).

```
PortalBundle
  Course Entity Extends TrainingBundle Course
    Add a Many to Many Relationship with another PortalBundle Entity


TrainingBundle
  Course Entity
    One to Many Relationship with Lesson Entity
```

**Is this even possible?** I tried creating the TrainingBundle:Course Entity as a MappedSuperClass but this is not possible because the TrainingBundle:Course entity has a One to many relationship.

If I try to just extend the TrainingBundle:CourseEntity I get an error "The table with name 'Course' already exists.

Comment: How did you map your entities? Yaml, XML, annotations?

Comment: currently I have them mapped as annotations

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a mapped superclass - http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html.

If the restrictions on a mapped superclass don't work for your use case you may have to look at Class Table Inheritance to extend your entities. Class Table Inheritance is described a little further down on that same page.

Comment: Mapped Superclass will not work because I want to keep the TrainingBundle:Course relationships in tact (i.e 1-m Lessons) for the TrainingBundle to remain portable. Class table inheritance might work if I can declare the InheritanceType and DiscriminatorColumn/Map in the PortalBundle. I'll give that a try next.